# Google Analytics API - allowed dimension/metrics in segments

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, segment

I have server-side app creating Audiences with specific segments. I know the names of dimensions/metrics can differ for UI and API. Therefore I am using [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#q=reve&segments=true&cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,ad_exchange,doubleclick_for_publishers,doubleclick_for_publishers_backfill,lifetime_value_and_cohorts,channel_grouping,related_products,doubleclick_bid_manager,doubleclick_search) for checking the appropriate name in API.

Explorer settings:

- API names
- Only show allowed in segments

The problem is, that there are some dimensions/metrics which explorer tag as **"allowed in segment"** but I am getting error from API **"ga:xyz is not allowed in advanced segments."**

It is doing for example:

- ga:revenuePerUser
- ga:sessionsPerUser
- ga:transactionsPerUser
- ...

Do anyone know why? Is it bug in API documentation?

Comment: Is it a session or user based segment?  Perhaps the above are only allowed in user ones?

Comment: The segment looks like that: **users::condition::ga:revenuePerUser>5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation error. In the MetaData API, it is marked as "allowedInSegments": "false",

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1